# MDX Row Count and pagination

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx

How can I translate this MDX Query to get a count of all total records ? for doing paging in a webpage ?

```
SELECT { 
            [Measures].[Invoice Price], 
            [Measures].[Quantity], 
            [Measures].[Verified Total] 
        } 
            on columns, SubSet(
                            NONEMPTY(
                            (
                             [Distributor].[Distributor].[Distributor].ALLMEMBERS * 
                             [Product].[PA Description].[PA Description] * 
                             [Time].[Month Name of Year].[Month Name of Year].ALLMEMBERS *  
                             [Time].[Month Number of Year].[Month Number of Year].ALLMEMBERS 
                             ),
                             {
                                [Measures].[Invoice Price], 
                                [Measures].[Quantity], 
                                [Measures].[Verified Total]

                              }
                             )
                             ,0
                             ,5
                ) 
                DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME on Rows from [Reporting]
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[RowCount] AS
  SubSet(
     NONEMPTY(
       (
        [Distributor].[Distributor].[Distributor].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Product].[PA Description].[PA Description] * 
        [Time].[Month Name of Year].[Month Name of Year].ALLMEMBERS *  
        [Time].[Month Number of Year].[Month Number of Year].ALLMEMBERS 
       ),
       {
         [Measures].[Invoice Price], 
         [Measures].[Quantity], 
         [Measures].[Verified Total]
       }
     )
     ,0
     ,5
   ).COUNT
SELECT { 
         [Measures].[Invoice Price], 
         [Measures].[Quantity], 
         [Measures].[Verified Total],
         [Measures].[RowCount]
        } on 0
     , SubSet(
     NONEMPTY(
       (
        [Distributor].[Distributor].[Distributor].ALLMEMBERS * 
        [Product].[PA Description].[PA Description] * 
        [Time].[Month Name of Year].[Month Name of Year].ALLMEMBERS *  
        [Time].[Month Number of Year].[Month Number of Year].ALLMEMBERS 
       ),
       {
         [Measures].[Invoice Price], 
         [Measures].[Quantity], 
         [Measures].[Verified Total]
       }
     )
     ,0
     ,5
   ) 
   ON 1 
FROM [Reporting];
```

Although surely it is just 5...!

Comment: When running this I get 

Executing the query ...
The end of the input was reached.
Run complete

with no output